# Prevent overlapping of nodes in GoJs

Tags: gojs

I have a graph with details of its **node positions**.

[image: First graph]

I am trying to create another graph by simply expanding the node size.

[image: Second graph]

Everything works fine but the nodes in new graph are overlapping each other. I understand the reason is because of the nodes which are now bigger, but is there a *GoJs way* to prevent overlapping by following the location points I've given?

**Note:** I've just used panels, shapes and textblocks. I've **not used** Parts, Layouts, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you scale up the x and y values of each node's **Node.location** by the ratio that you have scaled up the sizes of the nodes.

```
const ratio = ...;  // the new scale factor for each node
myDiagram.commit(d => {
  d.nodes.each(n => {
    n.scale *= ratio;
    n.location = n.location.copy().scale(ratio, ratio);
  });
})
```